# CSS elements seem to overlay when zooming in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a HTML site with CSS styling and run into the following issues:

1. Depending on monitors size, my HTML element's **positioning changes**. So if It's a bigger screen, then lets say everything fits correctly. But if you open it in a smaller screen, not everything is displayed!
2. If I zoom in the browsers view, the elements begin to overlay each other - yet I want to **stay where they are** (even if that means they wont be displayed on screen due to a high zoom IN).

(I cannot post images yet, so I'm adding a link to the picture to explain abit more):

[image]

I am also posting a fiddle where you can see my CSS for the MENU and the HTML part that is connected with it:

```
I have to write some code, but my code is too long and wouldn't look nice.
```

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q79LJ/6/)

It would be really nice of you, if you can help me out here. If it's a problem more complicated to explain on how to fix it, I'd kindly ask, if you can change my fiddle to a working version (if it's not too much to ask).

I have checked already similar Questions, but there were no efficient answers that helped me to solve my problem.

Comment: your fiddle has unclosed `<li>`s :)

Comment: Tidy up the code and show us the relevant fragments.

Comment: your fiddle's elements dont overlay on zoom in chrome... honestly mate, if you have a specific question which can be answered then feel free to ask, but jumping into deep waters and saying "my code doesnt work" wont lead far... my advice to you is to at least go over the tutorials [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/) and learning how things work first

Comment: Why is this that community on StackOverflow are never happy to help? You comment on my mistake, that I have unclosed <li> - yes, my bad, I forgot to copy it over. But I asked about my main issue.
The Elements ARE overlaping, as you can see in my screenshot

Comment: On which browser/version do you see the screenshot you provided ?

Comment: We're happy to help when we have enough elements/information to help :)

Comment: "Why is this that community on StackOverflow are never happy to help" if we weren't happy to help, we wouldn't spend time on commenting... and the elements dont overlap on my chrome 35, unfortunately i cannot debug images so unless i am able to recreate the issue i can only guess: try adding in the `<ul>` css `whitespace:nowrap;`

Comment: Works as expected on Chrome 35 / Mac

Comment: Same on Firefox 30. I'm happy to test on all my browsers because you didn't tell us on which browser you're having this issue.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome and also Firefox. Here, I updated my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q79LJ/6/  now you can see the overlaying for sure (hopefully)  --> One of the buttons is not displayed in this fiddle (but it works in my HTML maybe something didnt copy over correclty, because now i have entire CSS in one code due fiddle)

Comment: _Why is this that community on StackOverflow are never happy to help?_ Please be a little bit more grateful to the people here which are trying to help you for free and without any benefit for themselves. Non-closed elements can cause problematic behaviour in many browser, so that could even have been the reason for the problem. Also, it is your responsibility as question asker to make sure the question is correct. Please don't react negatively when people point out your mistakes - They want them to be fixed so they can actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

So, the reason that you are getting this behavior comes down to the fact that you have set your two buttons to each be fixed with the position set to %.  This means the position of each is calculated as a percent relative to the 'viewport' (the browser window).  If the window is only 500px wide, then your 40% left position button sits at 200px and the 50% left position button sits at 250px, thereby causing them to overlap.

Generally, I would not use fixed positioning here, but it's really not possible to provide a better alternative without seeing more of your code.  (Perhaps you'd like to get feedback in general by posting all of your code on [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)).

You can solve the problem by wrapping both elements in a div and give that div your fixed position values for the first element and allow the second button to be positioned relative to the first.

Here's an example of that approach and your updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/a83qC/):

Change your HTML:

```
<div class="btns">
    <a href='index.html' class='button_lay'>NONE</a>
    <a href='dft.html' class='button_dft'>NONE2</a>
</div>
```

Add a rule for the .btns class to your css and remove the fixed positioning from each of the buttons:

```
.btns {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80%;
    left: 40%;
    min-width: 300px;
}
```